# how can I call data when jQueryMobile page changed

Tags: jquery-mobile

Im building a browser-based app by jQueryMobile and facing a problem: Now I have a single HTML contains multiple "data-role=page" sections each of them will call backend to grab content once activated.

```
$('body').bind('pagechange',function(event){
    //grab content base on page id here, working!!!
});
```

However, if user reload the page by press "refresh" button on browser how can I detect and call backend page?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the pageshow event. Something like this:

```
$("[data-role=page]").live('pageshow',function(event, ui){
    var myId = $.mobile.activePage.attr('id');
    // do something
});
```